# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.antlr.runtime.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I am trying to check similarities between two codes, I need the id of Tokens from lexer,
but I don't know why I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.antlr.runtime.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token
```

Here is the code:

```
final CommonTokenStream tokens;
tokens = new CommonTokenStream();

tokens.setTokenSource(lexer);
tokens.LT(10); // force load

Antlr3JavaParser parser = new Antlr3JavaParser(tokens);
List tokenList = tokens.getTokens();
for (int i = 0; i < tokenList.size(); i++) {
    Token t = (Token) tokenList.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Is there an org.antlr.runtime.Token interface? Maybe try changing your Token import to that.

Answer (score 0):

`org.antlr.runtime.CommonToken` implements `org.antlr.runtime.Token` and *not* `antlr.Token`. You need to import `org.antlr.runtime.Token`.

The exception occurs when converting an `org.antlr.runtime.CommonToken` to an `antlr.Token` in `Token t = (Token) tokenList.get(i);`